# How to check a checkbox control properly in code in VB.NET? (VS2017 debugger crashes with my code)

Tags: vb.net

I am reading a few configuration values from a config file inside the Form_Load event...

I then set certain values according to the config file (basically just the last user settings stored at program shutdown)

Most of it works fine except the status of a checkbox....it causes the debugger to stall and the code afterwards is not executed anymore...

I am certainly doing something wrong. Not sure if it my have something to do that the checkbox is inside a groupbox?

See my simple code:

```
 If ConfigString(1) = "1" Then chkSendTX.Checked = True
 If ConfigString(1) = "0" Then chkSendTX.Checked = False
```

I also tried .checkedstate instead of .checked but that didn't work either.
Google did not yield any examples that would work either.

So I am looking for some expert here to help me out :-) Thanks...

Comment: My crystal ball says that you are using Win7: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4934010/17034

Comment: What error are you getting and on what line does it occur.

Comment: Yes I am using Win7...I will try to move the code out of the Form_Load event....it's a bit annoying. Thanks Hans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by removing it from Form_Load event into Form_Shown event....thanks for the help guys.